# How to get unique value after removing space and group by some different column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, rails-postgresql, groupwise-maximum

I have a table like

```
id type note
1   A   ab cd
1   B   cdef
1   A   abd
1   A   abcd
```

I want to get all the unique notes after removing space so my result will be like this

```
id type note
1   A   ab cd
1   A   abd
1   B   cdef
```

because after removing space **ab cd** and **abcd** will be same. 
I am using Postgres. Please note that id column in not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a classic groupwise maximum but you just group it on an expression not column

```
SELECT id, type, note FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT ON(replace(note,' ',''))
     id
     ,type
     ,note
   FROM table1
   ORDER BY replace(note,' ','')
  ) AS q
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0ab68/1)

Comment: its only returning unique value ... based on id , type .. not multiple records.

Comment: It works exactly as in the example (see the fiddle). If it doesn't work as you wanted it to then please improve the question.

Comment: Hay it works on.. I had a different data set which confuse me .. It works :+1

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be using Rails (according to your tags), you could also use ActiveRecord to get all of your unique instances of `note`, disregarding any spaces:

```
WhateverModel.pluck("REPLACE(note, ' ', '')").uniq
```